# pros and cons of saving XSL to file vs. db

Tags: database, xslt

If I had a dynamically generated XSL document and needed to persist it, would there be any pros or cons to writing it to a file or saving it in a DB? Feels like a coin toss at the moment (although db persistence would be easier of the two ), but I wonder if I'm ignoring security implications (performance?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it to a file.  XSL files can have things like

```
<xsl:include href="../some_other_file.xsl" />
```

which won't work if it's in a database.  You can get around this with XML catalogs, but really, XSL was designed for file systems.

**Edit:** I was wrong.  XSL was designed for URIs and you can get this to work in a database.  See the comments.

Comment: No, XSL's include mechanism was designed for URIs.  It's easy to map relative URIs to relative file-system addresses, so you're quite right that inclusions etc. are easy in file systems.  But they are equally easy in database systems if the user understands how the database system handles relative URIs.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen You're right. I forgot about URIs.  I try to forget a lot of my XSLT development.  I stand corrected and offer up a humble Oracle doc about my ignorance.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb15dbu.htm