# Best place to place XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

We have a web service that receives an XML string as input. The first thing the service does (or should do) is validate the received XML string against a pre-defined and agreed upon XML schema.

What would be the best way of storing and accessing this schema?

1. A physical .xsd file in the same location as the web service?
2. A constant string in the code file of the web service?
3. A string value in a resource file of the project?
4. Somewhere in the web config?
5. In a database?

I don't think options (2) and (3) would be the best since the schema might change and then we'll need to change the code. Then again, if the XML structure changes, we'll need to change the code anyway in order to parse the XML correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to re-invent SOAP web services?

Comment: It would help to understand the deployment environment and programming language that you're using for this web service.

Comment: We recieve some XML from a remote system and need to parse the information in a VB.NET web service before writing it to databases and files.
@leppie would you please elaborate a little?

Comment: @that0th3rGuy: Oh sorry, I thought you have a web service, and not just using a (stupid) one. The web service should expose an XSD as part of the WSDL. Use svcutil.exe to generate client classes.

Comment: `...We recieve some XML from a remote system...`. Who decides the structure and content of the xml? is it you or the *remote-system* guy? `...if the xml structure changes...` who decides this change? please clarify. Please also state, are you using WCF? plain-old ASMX? barebones HttpListner?

Comment: @inquisitive: I'm not the remote-system guy and I don't decide the structure and/or the changes. The web-service is "plain-old" ASMX.

Comment: @leppie: The WSDL exposed XSD you are referring to; isn't that the XSD for the web service and the request? Or do you mean I can define the expected XML format in the included XSD to verify the value of one of the parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go through your options and offer some input on each.

> 1.) A physical .xsd file in the same location as the web service?

This is a good idea and probably your best option.  Giving it a URI/URL means that it's easily accessible to those outside, plus you can easily version each XSD and provide a new URL to each one.

> 2.) A constant string in the code file of the web service?

This doesn't sound fun to maintain.  In general, I like to keep my interface separate from my implementation, and my configuration kept separate from anything else.  With this option, you're coupling these things together.  I wouldn't recommend this.

> 3.) A string value in a resource file of the project?
>
> 4.) Somewhere in the web config?

I wouldn't recommend either of these just because you're making it harder to separate it out from the rest of the project.  It just seems awkward.  Still, it's not a terrible idea.

> 5.) In a database?

I used to not recommend this because I assumed it would mess with your `<xsd:include />` elements not being able to point to other files, thus limiting you to only the simplest of schemas, but I was [set straight in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202151/pros-and-cons-of-saving-xsl-to-file-vs-db/) where I learned URIs are not the same as URLs.  Databases are a legitimate place to store XML schemas, although my personal preference is to just store them on the filesystem.

In the end, I would say go with option 1.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is carefully written and ignores attributes and elements it does not know, a properly designed extension of the XML schema would not need any re-write of your code.
This means option 2 and 3 would not be the optimal way.

Including the schema into the web configuration may be a bit difficult - as it may involve XML within XML, which is possible but may be a bit cumbersome to maintain.

In most projects, the database contains data, but no configuration settings.

Hence, the most natural location for most projects would be option 1.

But YMMV, the best suggestion would be to put it where other configuration information of similar type is located in your project, as this is the location administrators and maintainers will search it in case something needs goes wrong, or something needs to be changed.